# ReactJS: Which lifecycle method should I use to detect change in props?

Tags: reactjs

I have a Table component to display User information and a Form component to receive user input. It receives user input and saves them to the table. There is also an option to edit a table row. On click of Edit, I have to load the table row details to the Form component. I am trying to solve this use case but I am running into issues. If I click Edit the first time, the table row gets loaded to the Form. When the form is open, if I click Edit on another row, the Form does not get updated. My question is, which lifecycle method should I use to get this change? I am currently using `componentDidMount` but that isn't the right way to do it.

```
// In table component
<FormComponent userRow={this.state.userRow}
               handleSaveRow={this.state.handleSaveRow}
```

```
// Form Component
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    age: ''
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  if(this.props.userRow !== null) {
    this.setState({
      firstName: this.props.userRow[firstName],
      lastName: this.props.userRow[lastName],
      age: this.props.userRow[age]
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you post FormComponent ? Where is FormComponent picking values from? state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **componentDidUpdate**. In componentDidUpdate you can check if the current props are different than previous props like so;

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.userRow && this.props.userRow !== prevProps.userRow) {
     this.setState({
      firstName: this.props.userRow[firstName],
      lastName: this.props.userRow[lastName],
      age: this.props.userRow[age]
     });
  }
}
```

Also in React 16 or above you can use **getDerivedStateFromProps**. It is called before render so **it does update state without re-rendering the component** which is more performant, but it takes nextProps, prevState as arguments so you can check **if next props are different than previous state rather than previous props**. Also there is *no setState* here, this method just returns new state. It has some side efffects according to [this article](https://alligator.io/react/get-derived-state/) though.

```js
getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
  if (nextProps.userRow && 
     (nextProps.userRow[firstName] !== prevState.firstName ||
      nextProps.userRow[lastName] !== prevState.lastName   ||
      nextProps.userRow[age] !== prevState.age
     )) {
      return {
        firstName: nextProps.userRow[firstName],
        lastName: nextProps.userRow[lastName],
        age: nextProps.userRow[age]
      };
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using componentDidUpdate(prevProps). In the React dev tools I see that the props do get updated. But the values that show in the form are not getting updated. In other words, state doesn't get updated even when props change

Comment: Can you try console logging something after if statement?

Comment: componentDidUpdate() doesn't get called for initial render though right? how about getDerivedStateFromProps()? Do I need to use componentDidMount() along with one of these two hooks?

Comment: You can use one of them, but componentDidUpdate runs after initial render but getDerivedStateFromProps runs before render as far as I know

Answer (score 2):

If you are on React 16 or above, you can use `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)`  else `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`. (in FormComponent)

In these methods, update state with new user info if upcoming props are different than current state.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if (nextProps.userRow !== this.state.userRow) {
     this.setState({
      firstName: nextProps.userRow[firstName],
      lastName: nextProps.userRow[lastName],
      age: nextProps.userRow[age]
     });
  }
}
```

or

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  if (props.userRow && (props.userRow != state.userRow)) {
      return {
        firstName: props.userRow[firstName],
        lastName: props.userRow[lastName],
        age: props.userRow[age]
      };
  }
}
```